# issue using Azure Mobile Services framework with swift on iOS - EXC_BAD_ACCESS while saving table records to class property

Tags: azure, swift, azure-mobile-services, xcode6

I cannot use Azure Mobile Services from a swift iOS app.

I think that the issue is related to the closure access to self.items property.

I already tried to build the dev branch from github, but I receive the same error.

[error](https://www.dropbox.com/s/67ynpude65kxdxg/Screenshot%202014-06-18%2000.13.37.png)

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0xa0)

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class AVZItemsTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {
    let url = "https://XYZ.azure-mobile.net/"
    let key = "XYZ"
    let tableName = "XYZ"
    var items : AnyObject[]!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.loadData()
    }

    func loadData() {
        var client = MSClient(applicationURLString: url, withApplicationKey: key)
        var table = client.tableWithName(self.tableName)
        table.readWithCompletion({
            (results: AnyObject[]!, totalCount: Int!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if (error != nil)  { NSLog(String(format: "%@", error.debugDescription!))}
            // without this line everything "goes fine"
            self.items = results
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the issue was related to the table declaration:

```
var table = client.tableWithName(self.tableName)
```

I changed that variable as class property

```
import UIKit

class AVZItemsTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {
    let url = "https://XYZ.azure-mobile.net/"
    let key = "XYZ"
    let tableName = "XYZ"
    var items : NSDictionary[]()
    var table : MSTable?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    var client = MSClient(applicationURLString: url, withApplicationKey: key)
        self.table = client.tableWithName(self.tableName)
        self.loadData()
    }

    func loadData() {
        self.table!.readWithCompletion({
            (results: AnyObject[]!, totalCount: Int!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if (error != nil)  { NSLog(String(format: "%@", error.debugDescription!))}
            self.items = results as NSDictionary[]
        })
    }
}
```

Now everything is going better :)

Thanks to phillipv :)

Answer (score 2):

In the Swift Todo quickstart I put together, I used

```
var records = NSDictionary[]()
...
self.records = results as NSDIctionary[]
```

I'd think var record: NSDictionary[]? should also work as well.

see: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/blob/dev/quickstart/iOS-Swift/ZUMOAPPNAME/ZUMOAPPNAME/ToDoTableViewController.swift#L50

Comment: same error :( but thanks for the hint :) I will try to see if there are any difference between the demo and my app :)